# KeyError: 'data' in python3

Tags: json, python-3.x, graphql, python-3.7

I am using graphql in order to show the number of pull requests made by a user. The query works fine when I ran it on the graphql explorer by GitHub. However when I run the script, it shows KeyError and that the expected value is string. Even though the username entered is converted to a string.

Here's the code:

```
accessToken = "###################################"        
headers = {"Authorization": "bearer "+ accessToken }

    def getpullRequests(username):
        topic_query = """
        query {
        repositoryOwner(login:""" + str(username) + """) {
            login 
            ... on User {
            name
            avatarUrl
            pullRequests(last: 100){
                nodes{
                id
                createdAt
                additions
                deletions
                }
            }
            } 
        }
        } 
        """
        request = requests.post('https://api.github.com/graphql', json={'query': topic_query}, headers=headers)
        if request.status_code == 200:
            result = request.json()
            prsdata = {}
            for pr in result['data']['repositoryOwner']['pullRequests']['nodes']:
                prdata = {}
                if re.match(r'^2019-10', pr['createdAt']):
                    prdata['createdAt'] = pr['createdAt']
                    prdata['additions'] = pr['additions']
                    prdata['deletions'] = pr['deletions']
                    prsdata[pr['id']] = prdata
            if prsdata:
                print(prsdata)
            else:
                print("No PRs made in Hacktoberfest")

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        username = input("Enter the GitHub username: ")
        getpullRequests(username)
```

However on debugging after some tries I found out that the problem is with this line:

```
for pr in result['data']['repositoryOwner']['pullRequests']['nodes']:
```

On running the code, the error I face is :

```
Enter the GitHub username: adiaux
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 47, in <module>
    getpullRequests(username)
  File "script.py", line 33, in getpullRequests
    for pr in result['data']['repositoryOwner']['pullRequests']['nodes']:
KeyError: 'data'
```

Someone please help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.
Basically I used the graphQL variables and made the variable into a dict, like this:

```
 variables=dict({
        "name":str(username)
    })
```

However accordingly I modified the the query by including:

```
 query ($name:String!){
    repositoryOwner(login:$name){
        login 
        ... on User {
        name
        avatarUrl
        pullRequests(last: 100){
            nodes{
            id
            createdAt
            additions
            deletions
            }
        }
        } 
    }
    }
```

Thanks to whoever tried to solve this :)